# Globally disable EntityManager cache in jboss

Tags: caching, jboss, entitymanager

Is it possible to disable caching with EntityManager in some jboss config?

I'll explain. I have some final "ear" of our product that is using EntityManager through hibernate (something like this, i an newbie to this) and I need to test some behaviour. The easy way for me is to change(remove, create) state of entities direct in the database. But after i did this, the application remain to find old values for some time. I've read about some jboss cache, that is used for entity-manager.

So, for testing, i want to disable EntityManager cache, but it can not be disabled on application-level, only on jboss-level.

In brief: i need application **always** to reload actual entity state, because it can be edited in database with come other application. And its impossible to disable caching on application-level(hibernate.xml and other)

PS: jboss 4.2.3, ejb3, hibernate3

Answer (score 1):

The cache you are referring to is probably the `PersistenceContext`. It cannot be disabled. You can only tweak it's scope. In a Java EE environment, the scope of the persistence context is the transaction per default. So if you need for some changes to take effect immediately, you can extract these changes (including fetching the entities in question) into a separate method and annotate it to require a new transaction:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

Once the method returns, all changes are committed.

You could also use bean managed transactions, so you can control the commit yourself. For this, annotate your bean with `@TransactionManagement( TransactionManagementType.BEAN )` and use `UserTransaction`:

```
@Resource
private UserTransaction tx;
...
tx.begin();
//do stuff
tx.commit();
```

Comment: It is not good to edit production code for testing issues, so i want to configure test-ready environment. I need changes to take effect soon after i commited smth to database. Maybe it is not allowed to disable cache, but there should be some properties to adjust refresh time or smth like this.